# How do you pass a struct Pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am a little confused by how pointers are passed in functions by reference?

For instance, here's some code that I have written
(I didn't copy the entire function, just the part of it that is relevant)

```
  metadata * removeBlock(metadata *first)
{

    metadata *temp = first;
    if(first == NULL || first -> prev == NULL)
        {
            first -> in_use = 1;
            first = NULL;
            return temp;
        }
}
```

What I want is that when the function returns, the original value passed in should be set to NULL. 
Here is how I call the function, (this line of code will pull a metadata structure from a region in heap, it works correctly, I have debugged and made sure that after this, struct really points to a valid metadata struct)

```
metadata *strct = ((metadata *)ptr - sizeof(metadata));
removeBlock(strct);
```

However, after this method returns, strct is still the same value it was before I had passed it in the function. I tried passing in &strct, but that just threw an invalid cast exception. What is the best way to pass in the struct as an argument?

Thankyou.

Comment: C simply doesn't have `pass-by-reference`,it only has `pass-by-value`.Even when passing pointers,it is essentially `pass-by-value`.

Comment: Your function has problems. For example, if `first == NULL` you go ahead and dereference the NULL pointer attempting to set `first->in_use`.

Comment: I have not had any case when the user passed in a NULL, although it is a good idea to eliminate the check so that it never actually happens. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you want is a good design - if the user of your function wants the pointer set to null (why?) it would make sense to reset the value using the return value from your function.

Anyway, you'll want a pointer-to-a-pointer, like so:

```
metadata* removeBlock(metadata** first) {

    metadata* temp = *first;
    if( temp == NULL ) return temp;

    if( temp->prev == NULL ) {
        temp->in_use = true;
        *first = NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}

metadata* strct = ((metadata*)ptr - sizeof(metadata));
removeBlock(&strct);
```

Comment: How is this different?Isn't `first=NULL` where `first` is a pointer same as `*first=NULL` where `first` is a pointer to pointer?

Comment: I tried using double pointers like you said, and it did exactly what it was supposed to. Thankyou.

Comment: @SheerFish No, it's one level deeper. `*first=NULL` where `first` is a pointer-to-pointer leaves `first` as it was. It's NULLing the thing *pointed to* (which happens also to be a pointer).

Comment: @luserdroog Thanks.Seems like I am still groggy after waking up in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

As @SheerFish said, all we have in C is pass-by-value. However, one can simulate pass-by-reference with a pointer.

```
void func(struct foo **fooptr) { *fooptr = 0; }
int main(int argc, char **argv) { struct foo *fooptr; func(&fooptr); }
```

This is passing a pointer `ptr` to the variable's value (never mind if that value was a pointer), allowing the function to play with the original value with `*ptr`. This technique is sometimes called pass-by-address, and is the closest C has to pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass by 'reference in C', you're going to need to keep in mind referencing and de referencing via ->/** and *. This bit of code I wrote may help you a bit

```
    int delete_node(struct node** head, int target)
    {

        if(*head == NULL)
            return 0;                                                    
    if((*head)->data == target)
        {
            temp = *head;
            *head = (*head)->next;
            free(temp);
            return 1;
        }                                                    
}
```

Function call:

```
 delete_node(&head, data)
```

You're working with direct memory pointer manipulation. You're tossing the location of the struct in memory, de referencing it, then changing the value at that memory location.

Comment: Where does this `delete_node` comes from? ( not me that down voted )

Comment: I updated it to correct that. Forgot to specify that that was the function call at the bottom. This is just an example code piece I wrote for a C link list.

Comment: My data is not an integer, this is part of a doubly linked list, without any data. It is just a location reference in a heap, that sits next to a block of data, so there is not exacly any data to be removed. However, like you suggested, using double pointers worked. thankyou.

Comment: I know it's not the same reference data. The point was to show how pointer data/struct data is thrown around and referenced in function calls. I am glad to hear that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read all of the details, but this part jumped out as incorrect:

```
(metadata *)ptr - sizeof(metadata)
```

Pointer arithmetic is done in the units of the type, whereas `sizeof` gives you measurements in bytes.

So I suspect what you're trying to say is:

```
(metadata *)(((char*)ptr) - sizeof(metadata))
```

This is also making some assumptions about the machine you're running on, i.e. `metadata` may need to be padded to ensure that the fields are properly aligned for this use.  If `sizeof(metadata)` is not a multiple of the word size, this will fail on a lot of architectures.  (But x86 will let it slide, albeit with performance costs and some implications like atomic ops not working on the fields.)

Comment: @Elazar - First question: Should be the same, but I wanted to be a bit more explicit.  Second question: it is absolutely *not* an irrelevant matter, the compiler is not guaranteed to add any padding on your behalf.

Comment: Not exactly. In my heap, a metadata struct stays in a heap next to a block of data. So, when the user gives reference to that block of data, I try to find that metadata struct by subtracting the size. It works, I have not had to cast it specially, although I guess your way is more syntactially correct and foolproof.

Comment: @Franzd'Anconia - Read again.  You're not subtracting the size, you're subtracting the size *squared*.  Quoting myself: "Pointer arithmetic is done in the units of the type, whereas sizeof gives you measurements in bytes".  So you are subtracting `sizeof(metadata) * sizeof(metadata)` bytes.

Comment: @asveikau - sorry, I deleted my second questions after I read your explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

pointers are passed by value. *anything* in c is passed by value. so in order to change the pointer passed to the function, it should receive `metadata **first`.

besides, you should use

```
metadata *strct = ((metadata *)ptr - 1);
```

as pointer arithmetic is done with multiples of sizeof(*p). so this is equivalent to

```
metadata *strct = ((metadata *)((char*)ptr - sizeof(metadata)));
```